# Por que al consumir un servicio WCF o API REST la primera invocacion siempre es mas lenta que las posteriores

Tags: c#, api, soap, wcf, postman

Tengo una duda, por que cuando consumimos un método de un wcf o api la primer llamada o ejecucion siempre es la mas lenta a las siguientes?

Existe alguna explicación o forma de evitarlo

Comment: que demora tiene? al mismo endpoint?

Comment: Puede ser por el ssl handshake y la resolución de dns

Comment: si demora o respuesta del endpoint que se consume, pero siempre en el primer llamado, las peticiones posteriores no presentan la lentitud